# Optional Discount textbox gives 0 value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to calculate the discount of **totalAmount** by the sum of **quantity**
and **unitPrice**.The thing is discount can be optional.It can be use or not it depends on the user if he/she going to input some value in the discount textbox.

What I did is leave the discount textbox empty if I am not going to input a value on it,
but my **totalAmount** still gives me a zero value for an output.

```
 protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double quantity, unitPrice,totalAmount;

        double discount;

        double d;

        bool canProcess = true;

        //Quantity
        if (!double.TryParse(lblQuantity.Text, out quantity))
        { 
            //Conversion Failed
            string script = "alert(\"Quantity cannot be converted\");";

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                "ServerControlScript", script, true);
        }
        //UnitPrice
        if (!double.TryParse(txtUnitPrice.Text, out unitPrice))
        { 
            //Conversion Failed
            string script = "alert(\"Unit Price cannot be converted\");";

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                "ServerControlScript", script, true);
        }
        if (!double.TryParse(txtDisc.Text, out discount))
        {
            //Conversion Failed
            string script = "alert(\"discount cannot be converted\");";

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                "ServerControlScript",script,true);
        }
        if (canProcess)
        {
          d = quantity * unitPrice;

            totalAmount = ((d*discount)/100);
            lblTotalAmount.Text = totalAmount.ToString();
        }
    }
    //#calculator end
}
```

Comment: You need to check if `discount` is greater than `0.0`. Change `totalAmount = ((d*discount)/100);` to `totalAmount = (discount > 0.0 ? (d*discount)/100 : d);` . In C# `Double` is a value type, meaning, even if it not initialized, a default value of `0.0` is stored in your variable. So, your calculation statement becomes `totalAmount = (d*0.0)/100;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want discount to be optional, than decide how you want to calculate your amount:

```
    if (canProcess)
    {
        d = quantity * unitPrice;

        if(discount == 0)
        {
            totalAmount = d;// any calculation
        }
        else
        {
            totalAmount = ((d*discount)/100);
        }

        lblTotalAmount.Text = totalAmount.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to check first discount is greater then 0, then you can calculate the total amount

```
if (canProcess)
{
    d = quantity * unitPrice;

    if(discount == 0)
    {
        totalAmount = d;
    }
    else
    {
        totalAmount = ((d*discount)/100);// if here d is 0 your total amt will be 0.
    }

    lblTotalAmount.Text = totalAmount.ToString();
}
```